# Recovering SVN repository from manual backup

Tags: macos, svn

My Mac OS X system that was having svn server repository has crashed. I dont have svn backup. But I have backup of my whole hard disk data that includes "SVNSever" folder. With the help of this "SVNServer" folder can I restore my svn system back. The contents of SVNServer folder are:

```
/conf
/db
/hooks
/locks
format
README.txt
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The set of directories/files you showed looks like a regular SVN repository. So probably you don't need to restore the repository - you already have it. Just try to access it like any other repository on disk.